# Load sidebar onOpen google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am trying to load the sidebar when the page opens.  I have important information that i was readily available for them to see.  How can i load the sidebar when page is opened?  I also could do onEdit if need be.

```
function onOpen(){

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createAddonMenu()
  .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
  .addItem('Show dialog', 'showDialog')
  .addSeparator()
  .addToUi();

// Display sidebar if auto-sidebar is enabled
showSidebar();


SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Information')
.addItem('Help', 'showPicker')
.addToUi();

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Changelog')
.addItem('Changelog', 'changeLog')
.addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
.addToUi();


////Get user name and 


var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Discovery Sheet');
var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
Logger.log(email);
name.getRange('a38').setValue(email);

 }
```

Or like this one?

```
function OnEdit() {

 var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Changelog')
  .setTitle('Changelog')
  .setWidth(300);
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
  .showSidebar(html);

}
```

Comment: Have you tried either? Note that there [are limits](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions) on what the functions that are bound to simple triggers can do. Also note, that `#javascript` is not the right tag when dealing with UI / code specific / exclusive to Google Apps Script.

Comment: I have tried these but they fail to run.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser()

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you posted that link.  All that does is get the user information.

Comment: Did you read the bits about simple triggers and accessing information about the current user from functions that run without authorization?

Comment: I did read that.  Its unclear to me though that a sidebar wouldn't load if it doesn't contain executables.

Comment: Your code would have execute a couple of years ago but Google has decided to restrict the use of the automated sidebar display for security reasons... I find it also very annoying but they have the power ! ;) So from now on every user needs to have its own installed trigger ( that can be programmatically added). By the way, it will continuously generate error messages telling you that you don't have permission to call showSidebar... I believe Google had good reasons to do so ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function anOnOpen(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Tools')
  .addItem('Sidebar', 'loadSidebar')
  .addToUi();
  loadSidebar();
}


function loadSidebar(){
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('simplesidebar');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}
```

You can add anything you want in the html with getElementById and innerHTML.  I often use the JQuery ready function to call and apps script which returns the desired html contents.  Or you can use an HTML Template. Personally, I never use templates.

Comment: Note for this `anOnOpen` to run, an installed trigger is required.

Comment: True.  I don't feel compelled to do everything for the questioner.

Comment: [18-03-15 16:40:09:139 EDT] Execution failed: You do not have permission to call showSidebar (line 86, file "Code") [0.918 seconds total runtime]

Comment: This is really frustrating as its such a simple call that it shouldn't need permissions.

Comment: See this bug report, the installable trigger will work for you but no one else... waiting for a fix as this used to work a few months ago.https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69238694#comment7

Comment: Its considered bad practice to open the sidebar or any dialogs on page open and is strongly discouraged in the documentation. I'd avoid doing this in future if possible.

Comment: Where is it discouraged?