# apps script onlycurrentdoc scope prevents usage of add-on in other documents

Tags: google-apps-script, scope, permissions, authorization, google-apps-script-addon

I published an add-on for Google Docs a few years ago, when add-ons were published to the Chrome webstore. I added the `@OnlyCurrentDoc` tag at the top of the main script, to narrow permissions: the add-on only ever has to edit the document that it is being used in, it never has to access any other documents in your Google Drive. At first it seemed to work great. Now that add-ons have transitioned to the GSuite Marketplace, I have updated and republished the add-on, but I am starting to get a number of notifications in the Stackdriver Error logs that some user "doesn't have permission to do that". I have kept all calls to scripts that require permissions within the scope of the "`onOpen`" function with a check for `"e.AuthMode === ScriptApp.AuthMode.Limited || e.AuthMode === ScriptApp.AuthModeFull`". Without any authorizations ("`e.AuthMode === ScriptApp.AuthModeNone`") the add-on pretty much can't do anything, it will just give an alert using "`DocumentApp.getUi().alert()`" to let the user know that they need to authorize the add-on in order for it to do anything.

So I'm wondering, what can be causing the "user doesn't have permission to do that" error? Does a script need permission even just to call "`DocumentApp.getUi()`" ? And yet I've seen examples in the Documentation saying that in case of `AuthModeNone`, you could still create a basic sidebar which doesn't require any particular permissions from the user, just so they're not left with nothing. However it does seem to me that creating any kind of UI such as a Sidebar or a Modal using `HtmlService` does require permissions, so I have avoided that, and yet I still see this error.

And now, I'm even noticing myself that when I install the add-on on a Google account (the add-on has been enabled in fact for any Google account, not just GSuite accounts), it is available in the document that was open when I installed it, but if I create a new document I get an empty menu for the add-on and I get the UI alert I created saying that the add-on needs permissions in order to work. I can then go to Manage add-ons: my add-on shows as being installed, if I click on the three dots for the contextual menu I see that "Use in this document" is unchecked. If I check it, the add-on menu won't be immediately available however if I refresh the page, it will sometimes be available and sometimes not.
If I then click on "Document add-ons" from the add-ons menu, a sidebar will open with my add-on logo and with a button "Use", which sometimes is blue (showing that it is enabled) and gives the same menu that my add-on creates, but sometimes will be grey and unclickable preventing me from enabling it for this document. Even a document refresh won't always fix it. I can see how this could be very frustrating for any given user trying to use the add-on.

Would it just be simpler to completely remove the `@OnlyCurrentDoc` tag (and relative permission scope in the GSuite Marketplace), so I can be sure the add-on is available for users when they need it? It seems counterintuitive to me that trying to protect a users privacy by using this narrowed scope actually creates an extra "permission required" line in the authorization dialog, it makes it seem like that user has to grant even more permissions when actually it means that narrower permissions are being asked. And then actually using the add-on becomes that much more frustrating, is it really worth using this narrowed scope? 
Here are some screenshots of what I myself am seeing, and I can imagine many other users are seeing (and if the experience is frustrating for a user they will be probably give a bad reputation score for an add-on, which was only trying to protect their privacy even more!)

[image: after installing the add-on, open a new document]
[image: add-on menu is in fact empty]
[image: add-on is installed but not enabled in document]
[image: add-on manually enabled for document]
[image: after refreshing the document, add-on menu was created this time, and going to "document add-ons" shows that it is enabled for this document; however sometimes this doesn't work and the "Use" button is greyed out!]
After refreshing the document, add-on menu was created this time, and going to "document add-ons" shows that it is enabled for this document; however sometimes this doesn't work and the "Use" button is greyed out!

Here is some sample code:

```js
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */

function onInstall(e){

  // Show instructions for usage automatically on first install
  openHelpSidebar(); //This uses the HtmlService to create the sidebar, do we need to check for authorization in order to be able to create and open this sidebar?

  // Add plugin menu to the toolbar (according to AuthMode)
  onOpen(e); 

}

function onOpen(e) {
  if(e && (e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.LIMITED || e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL)){
    // Initialize user preferences ONLY after user has granted permission to the Properties Service!
    //set default user properties using propertiesservice if not properties are not set yet
    ...
    //and create our menu items
    DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
      .addItem(__('Start',locale),         'openMainSidebar')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem(__('Instructions',locale),  'openHelpSidebar')
      .addItem(__('Send Feedback',locale), 'openSendFeedback')
      .addItem(__('Contribute',locale),    'openContributionModal')
      .addToUi();

  }
  else{ //if e.AuthMod === ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE
    //can I create any kind of UI if permissions are NONE? Seems to me that trying to create any kind of menu items that open a sidebar or modal with HtmlService will generate error if permissions are NONE
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('You must grant the correct permissions in order to use this add-on. To fix this, remove the add-on and install it again, granting the requested permissions.'); //perhaps try refreshing the page first? and try enabling for the document from the "Document add-ons" menu item in the add-ons menu?

  }

}
```

Of course this is only really testable when the add-on is actually published to the marketplace where non GSuite users can install it.

Comment: I have added some sample code, if it helps any. I think I'm just going to remove the @OnlyCurrentDoc scope, I already have users writing to me saying that they don't have a menu from the add-on after installing it.

Answer (score 2):

My rules of thumb for add-ons' simple triggers

1. `onInstall` should be used only to call `onOpen` (installing an add-on from the G Suite Marketplace is not creating a new file, by the other hand Google is blocking some actions like opening a dialog/sidebar)
2. `onOpen` should be used only to create the menu (doing anything else when `onOpen` is called by opening the file cause problems)
3. `onEdit` don't rely on the user property of the edit event object.

---

In this case the problem is that `onOpen` is trying to open an alert, so solely removing `@OnlyCurrentDoc` will not solve the problem (actually you could keep it), you have to remove the alert from the `onOpen` function.

---

Example of a dynamic menu based on [properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties).

From https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu(); // Or DocumentApp.
  if (e && e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE) {
    // Add a normal menu item (works in all authorization modes).
    menu.addItem('Start workflow', 'startWorkflow');
  } else {
    // Add a menu item based on properties (doesn't work in AuthMode.NONE).
    var properties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
    var workflowStarted = properties.getProperty('workflowStarted');
    if (workflowStarted) {
      menu.addItem('Check workflow status', 'checkWorkflow');
    } else {
      menu.addItem('Start workflow', 'startWorkflow');
    }
  }
  menu.addToUi();
}
```

---

Related

- [function onOpen() is not running](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13337599/1595451)
- [Load sidebar onOpen google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49308282/1595451)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214350/discussion-between-ruben-and-johnrdorazio).

Comment: and can a function being called by a user clicking on a menu item use the PropertiesService in any case? So even if permissions haven't been granted, I would still be able to check and set default permissions using PropertiesService not directly from onOpen, but only from a clicked menu item?